# How to join two unit operations (removeAll + create) into one

Tags: database, grails, spring-security, rollback

There is only a role per user in the application at the same time. To update a role, we previously remove all the current roles:

```
Integer roleId = params.roleSelector.toInteger()
def roleInstance = Role.findById(roleId)
UserRol.removeAll userInstance
UserRol.create userInstance, roleInstance
```

It is working, but I think it is more correct to perform removeAll and create as an unitary operation in order to a correct roll back if any error happens.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE 1**.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865055/spring-transactional-method-participating-transaction) that we can add @Transactional to make a method transactional. So if we write:

```
@Transactional
private def unitaryOperationUpdate {

    Integer roleId = params.roleSelector.toInteger()
    def roleInstance = Role.findById(roleId)
    UserRol.removeAll userInstance
    UserRol.create userInstance, roleInstance
}
```

If some error happened between removeAll and create, it would roll back correctly?

By the way, I'd like to know how to check myself if it is working: I asked that question in a separate thread: [How to check if a @transactional method perform rollback correctly in Grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548026/how-to-check-if-a-transactional-method-perform-rollback-correctly-in-grails)

Answer (score 2):

Services are the right place to do that, because they're already transactional. It means that if something goes wrong the transaction will be rolledback.

A side note is that only unchecked exceptions will rollback your transaction.

Comment: In my opinion, moving that code to a service would complicate the code innecesarely. Researching about transactional in controllers I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865055/spring-transactional-method-participating-transaction) that we can add @Transactional to make a method transactional. I updated my question (UPDATE 1)