# How to check if a @transactional method perform rollback correctly in Grails?

Tags: database, debugging, grails, rollback

Let's say we have a code like the following (I got the code frome [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18535717/how-to-join-two-unit-operations-removeall-create-into-one)):

```
@Transactional
private def unitaryOperationUpdate {

    Integer roleId = params.roleSelector.toInteger()
    def roleInstance = Role.findById(roleId)
    UserRol.removeAll userInstance
    UserRol.create userInstance, roleInstance
}
```

If some error happened between removeAll and create, how could we check ourselves if the rollback is working properly?

Comment: You can look at your data before and after. If rollback happens all changes should be reverted.

Comment: So how to produce an error between `removeAll` and `create` manually @Alidad?

Comment: You can throw exception. Not the best approach but you can test it.